# retrieving data by LINQ c#

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following issue

Customers and clients
Every client linked to a specific customer

-ClientID, ClientName, Customer_custID

-CustomerID, CustomerName

I want to retrieve every clients related to specific customer

This is my attempt

```
     data=clients.select(c=>c.clientName, 
        c.customerName.where(f>f.customerID==f.customer_custID)
```

I know it's terribly wrong but I am just learning lamda expression and LINQ, so pardon me

Comment: What do you know about specific customer? CustomerID or CustomerName? How client and customer classes look like?

Comment: Can you do `data = clients.where(c => c.Customer_custID == customerID);`?

Comment: Please read some more tutorials, come back and try again. This doesn't compile at all

Comment: you need to read more about lazy loading for convenience

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
IEnumerable<Client> clients = .... // your clients collection
IEnumerable<Customer> customers = .... // your customers collection

var relatedClients = from cst in customers
                     join cli in clients on cst.CustomerID equals cli.Customer_custID
                     where cst.CustomerID == 0 // your customerID
                     select cli;
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood what you wanted correctly. It assumes you know the Customer ID you're looking for before entering the query.

```
var clientsQuery = from clients in Client
                   where clients.Customer_custId == customerId
                   select clients;
```

You can then `foreach` over the query results.

```
foreach (var client in clientsQuery) 
{
    // Do stuff with your clients!
}
```